# agrep max.distance arguments in R

Tags: r, regex

I need some help with the specific arguments of the agrep package in R.

In terms of cost, all, insertions, deletions and substitutions each have a "maximum number/fraction of substitutions" integer or fraction input parameter.

Ive read the documentation on it, but I still cannot figure out some specifics:

- What is the difference of a "cost=1" and "all=1"?
- How is a decimal interpreted, such as "cost=0.1", "inserts=0.9", "all=0.25", etc.?
- I understand the basics of the Levenshtein Distance, but how is it applied in terms of the cost or all arguments?

Sorry if this is fairly basic, but like I said, the documentation I have read on it is slightly confusing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Not 100% certain, but here is my understanding:

- in `max.distance`, `cost` and `all` are interchangeable if you don't specify a `costs` argument (this is the next argument); if you do, then `cost` will limit based on the weighted (as per `costs`) costs of insertion/deletion/substitutions you specified, whereas `all` will limit on the raw count of those operations
- The fraction represents what fraction of the number of characters in your `pattern` argument you want to allow as insertion/deletions/substitutions (i.e. 0.1 on a 10 character pattern would allow 1 change).  If you specify `costs`, then it is the fraction of # of characters in pattern * max(`costs`), though presumably fractions in `max.distance{insertions/deletions/substitutions}` will be # of characters * corresponding `costs` value.

I agree that the documentation is not as complete as it could be.  I discovered the above by building simple test examples and messing around with them.  You should be able to do the same an confirm for yourself, particularly the last part (i.e. whether `costs` affects the fraction measure of `max.distance{insertions/deletions/substitutions}`), which I haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I have been in the process of building and testing searches as well. I was just wondering if anyone had more light to she on it. Thanks again.

Comment: As a follow up, do you know how large the "substring" that 'agrep' uses is? As I understand from the documentation it doesnt match the entire string, but I cannot figure out just how big the substring it uses is. Thanks.

Comment: @TomA, what matters is the size of the pattern, not the size of the substring the pattern matches.